How to correct problems when installing Flutter
I've been following Alan Pope's Blog Getting started with Flutter.
I think that there is an error in the instructions as "flutter config --android-studio-dir /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio" resulted with the flutter doctor:
john@Desktop:~$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Could not find the Android Studio installation at the manually configured path
"/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio".
So I tried "flutter config --android-studio-dir /snap/android-studio/current" and that gave:
john@Desktop:~$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that
the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.
So I did "sudo apt install android-sdk" to resolve that but still getting same error.
What do I do now?
PS I've looked in the Android Studio menu for an SDK Manager entry but don't see one.
Here is "flutter doctor - v" output:
john@Desktop:~$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS 6.8.0-40-generic,
locale en_GB.UTF-8)
• Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at
/home/john/snap/flutter/common/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 2663184aa7 (5 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
• Engine revision 36335019a8
• Dart version 3.5.3
• DevTools version 2.37.3
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
• Android SDK at /home/john/Android/Sdk
✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
Run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
✗ Android license status unknown.
Run flutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/to/linux-android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at google-chrome
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
• clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
• cmake version 3.16.3
• ninja version 1.10.0
• pkg-config version 0.29.1
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
• Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/161
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)
[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
• Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/current
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
• android-studio-dir = /snap/android-studio/current
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
6.8.0-40-generic
• Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 130.0.6723.58
[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Popey is contributor on Ask Ubuntu and can be contacted here

Hello! I just checked my laptop and I am indeed using android-studio from the snap store. Also, you might get more information if you run flutter doctor -vv

I did install android-studio using snap as per the instructions on Alan Pope's blog.

Thanks, Graham, for Popey;s details.
Here is some output from flutter doctor -vv:
Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[        ]     • Android SDK at /home/john/Android/Sdk
[        ]     ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
[        ]       Run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
[        ]       See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more
details.
[        ]     ✗ Android license status unknown.
[        ]       Run flutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK
licenses.
I've emailed Popey with the full output as not able to write it here.

"as not able to write it here" best to [edit] your question and update it with those details rather than attempt to post in comments. You can also tag @popey by placing an @ symbol before his nic at the start of a comment..

@graham Not able to paste the full output as it's too large to be in a comment. I forgot to use popey. I've previously been told off for updating a question rather than posting a comment.

only if the update is not related to the original question and should be a separate question in its own right.

I used config to set Android Studio Path & Android SDK Path. I was then able to accept the licenses, ignoring the Warning about XML. The Doctor gave a Warning about the Android Studio Version, which I hope doesn't matter:
john@Desktop:~$ flutter config --android-studio-dir="/snap/android-studio/current"
Setting "android-studio-dir" value to "/snap/android-studio/current".
john@Desktop:~$ flutter config --android-studio-dir="/snap/android-studio/current"
Setting "android-studio-dir" value to "/snap/android-studio/current".
john@Desktop:~$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Warning: Errors during XML parse:                                               
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
john@Desktop:~$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.4, on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS 6.8.0-40-generic,
    locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.


It looks like you may have incorrectly done:
flutter config --android-studio-dir /snap/android-studio/current/
When you should have done:
flutter config --android-studio-dir /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio
Then flutter doctor --android-licenses
Can you please flutter doctor --android-licenses -vv and paste the output to https://paste.debian.net/ then provide the link in your question.

@opey I did "flutter config --android-studio-dir /snap/android-studio/current/" because "flutter config --android-studio-dir /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio" gave the same problem as "flutter doctor --android licenses" and I noticed that there is no directory  /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio after running it. I've done the config (as you specified) again and the doctor again. The doctor ouput is at
https://paste.debian.net/1332738/

Correction: flutter doctor --android-licenses output is at
https://paste.debian.net/1333031/

Just noticed a typo: I should have typed @popey not @opey!
